# Passing string between screens

Tags: android, string

Consider 3 screens 1,2,3.I want string(price) in second screen from 1st screen. So in 1st screen i done putextra and got that in 2nd screen. Now i am navigating to 3rd screen and clicking back button in 3rd screen i am coming back to 2nd screen.Now that string(price) is showing as null.Please rectify me.

My code:

screen1:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IncomeDetails.class);
          intent.putExtra("grpsdb", grp1);
          startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Screen 2:

```
System.out.println("string="+intent.getStringExtra("grpsdb"));
           Cursor c = db.getIncometitle(intent.getStringExtra("grpsdb"));
           startManagingCursor(c);
```

Screen 3:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IncomeDetails.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
```

Comment: Ram kiran see my edited post..

Answer (score 2):

You are getting **null** value of `String price` because You are starting 2nd Activity **(IncomeDetails.class)** again from your 3rd Activity.

As I see, `IncomeDetails.class` is your 2nd Activity

and you are trying to start new 2nd Activity from 3rd Activity,

Using the code,

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IncomeDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

So just put `finish()` your 3rd activity in your button's click.. Instead of Starting 2nd new Activity again.

Something like,

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                <Your_3rd_Activity_Name>.finish();
            }
```

Also one more thing, start 3rd Activity from 2nd Activity using `stratActivityForResult()` and don't `finish()` 2nd Activity when you start 3rd Activity.

Comment: Thanks     user370305..String is coming..But it is showing some other error like this..can u help me??          07-19 18:15:54.479: E/Cursor(5234): Invalid statement in fillWindow()

Comment: user370305..When i am clicking back button ..the only line error is showing in my logcat...

Comment: You have to also setResult for 2 screen .

Comment: @DeepakSharma - Its not necessary, Its only required when you have some condition based result onActivityResult() of 2nd Activity.

Comment: @user370305 - Yes it is optional .

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startActivityForResult()` in you second activity and from there call activity 3. 
Then in activity 2 also use `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method.
Have a look at this example : http://rahulonblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html

Good Luck :)